# FPS camera up and down control

Tags: c#, unity

I am new to Unity. Now I am working with FPS camera. While pressing a key down arrow I want my camera to go down and again it come back to normal position. I am not getting any idea how to do it. Anyone, please help.

Answer (score 1):

With "go down" do you mean "tilt down" (as in "you lower your head") or "move down" (as in "you go down on your knees")?

Anyway, both are done by manipulating the `Transform`-component of your camera.

[`Camera.main.transform.Rotate(vector3);`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) rotates the currently active camera and setting [`Camera.main.transform.position = vector3;`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) moves the camera to a different position. When you already have a script in your scene which controls the camera, you need to make sure that the scripts don't interfere with each other. We can not see your scene setup, so we can not help you with that.

To find out if a user is currently holding the down key, use [`if (Input.GetKey("down")) {`](http://%60http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html%60)

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i want a smooth flow of camera. the camera have to tilt in y axis smoothly

Comment: @ManojBalajiM That's why it's important that you are specific in your questions. Please create a new question where you post your current camera control code and explain *exactly* how it behaves and *exactly* how you would like it to behave instead.

Comment: I Placed the camera in the player. the camera moves and jump with the player. if the player knees down the camera is not going down.

Comment: @ManojBalajiM As I wrote: Change the y-component of the camera position to control its height.

Comment: but the speed is very high. I want to tilt it slowly

Comment: @ManojBalajiM Then change the position of the camera by a small amount in every FixedUpdate until it has reached its destination.